# Running code post container load - Ressource loading

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to add the following behaviour to my jersey service:

- Load/Parse some files from the WEB-INF folder
- Store it in a singleton for quick access through the application's life.

Right now the solution that I have working is:

- Get the ServletContext for a ressource request
- For each request which needs to access the files, call this method getSomething(criteria, servletContext)

I have to pass the servletContext around so that I may use it to load the ressource using method getRessourceAsStream() as otherwise, I cant get the right path. This is my main pain point.

I'd like to be able to make the server automatically do this once the server is ready in the application server but I'm unable to find where exactly this could be done. This would eliminate the need for me to always pass the servletContext around and would allow me to use that singleton in some of my custom deserializers and would make the code that uses this singleton cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you find yourself wanting to do some work on startup in a Servlet application, use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), specifically the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)` method.